# Rewrite condition ! being ignored

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm working on rewrite rules. Every call made to the mobile website should be redirected to the non-mobile version (or in my example, to google) EXCEPT for a few pages. This has to work on several environments but they aren't the issue (asfar as I can see).

What I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} m\.(local\.|lcl\.|dvl\.|uat\.|)testsite\.be$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/categoryOne
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/categoryTwo
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.google.be/ [L,R=301]
```

If I surf to: http://m.lcl.testsite.be/categoryOne I get redirected ... Even though http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ says I shouldn't be.

So I simplified:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/categoryOne
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.google.be/ [L,R=301]
```

http://m.lcl.testsite.be/categoryOne

-> I get redirected

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/categoryOne
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.google.be/ [L,R=301]
```

http://m.lcl.testsite.be/categoryOne

I get redirected (which is good).

http://m.lcl.testsite.be/randomOtherCategory

-> I don't get redirected.

For me it looks like the negated statement is being ignored, which is strange considering I've used it elsewhere in the project aswel.

Any insight ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be other rules in your .htaccess changing `REQUEST_URI` to something else and causing negation based condition to pass.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/categoryOne
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.be/ [L,R=301]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable doesn't change its value after other rules.

Comment: Thank f****** god, or should I say anubhava ? :o

Could you explain more about how the request could be changed ?

Comment: `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: So there would need to be other apache rules changing my REQUEST_URI variable ? How would that happen ? I'm sorry I'm just really happy/curious about what exactly is going on.

Comment: The only issue here is that I couldn't validate with the carrot anymore.

In my example I use !^/categoryOne. Which isn't possible because it returns the entire thing.

Comment: Yes don't use `^` while matching with `THE_REQUEST` as I showed above.

Comment: Solved it by doing the following:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\w+\s/categoryOne